# Set variable for biggest file in the directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, size

If I do `dir` it lists multiple amount of random files and it shows its size in a column. How do I set a variable for a file that is biggest by size?

Eg.

```
$ dir
 Volume in drive C is file_dir

 Directory of C:\file_dir\

2019-05-05  21:33    <DIR>          .
2019-05-05  21:33    <DIR>          ..
2019-05-05  21:33        11 123 000 docs.pdf
2019-05-05  21:33         2 710 996 docs.txt
2019-05-05  21:33       152 708 423 archives.zip
```

`archives.zip` gets set as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `dir /?` you'll see the `/o` switch allows sorting by, among other attributes, size.  Use the `/b` switch for a bare listing (lists filename only), and capture the result using `for /F`.

You can either sort from smallest to largest for simplicity:

```js
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /o:s') do set "largest=%%~I"
```

Or from largest to smallest for efficiency

```js
@echo off & setlocal
set "largest="
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /o:-s') do if not defined largest set "largest=%%~I"
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the output of `dir /?`. It tells you, you can sort files by size with the `/os` switch (try `dir /os`) and print only the file name with the `/b` switch (try `dir /os /b`). Also  `/a-d` is useful to suppress folders.

To catch the last/biggest file into a variable, use a `for /f` loop (see `for /?` for details):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /os /b /a-d *') do set "biggest=%%a"
echo biggest file is %biggest%
```

(Note: this is batch file syntax. For use directly on the command line, use `%a` instead of `%%a` (both of them))